# JSF: Automatically replace Tags in Strings with CommandLinks

Tags: jsf-2.2

i have a String like "Hello [everyone]!". "Everyone" should be replaced with a commandLink that points to an Page-Object.

For Example:
My Code detects "[everyone]" and creates a new "Page" with the headline "everyone" in my JavaDB Database. Now i want that [everyone] will shown as an commandLink:

```
Hello <h:commandLink value="everyone" action="#{PageController.getPage(everyone)}" />
```

or something else.

ATM i have this code to display the text with the []-Tags:

```
<h:outputText value="#{PageController.currentPage.latestContent.text}"  />
```

Now what is the best practise to replace Tags (i.e. [XYZ]) with a specific commandLink? Or rather: how i can replace substrings with JSF-Tags (they should be rendered)? I have only found the possibility to create converter, but only examples to convert the complete string. :/ To find out the right substring i use Regulary Expressions.

Merry Christmas :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the best practise to replace Tags (i.e. [XYZ]) with a specific commandLinks? Or rather: how i can replace substrings with JSF-Tags (they should be rendered)? I have only found the possibility to create converter, but only examples to convert the complete string. :/ To find out the right substring i use Regulary Expressions.

Comment: Where does the string originate? Is it something someone types in to a form and that you then display?

Comment: Yes. It's like a wiki. The Text between the brackets reprasentate headlines for reference pages. There are various users that types Text in inputTextareas .. Mhh.. I want bbcode parsing.

Comment: My Problem is that i don't know how to generate commandLinks outside of the XHTML file and replace substring with these commandLinks. Even tough i don't know how to set an specific object as an action (outside of the XHTML file).

Comment: There is no particular reason they have to be commandLinks. Just look at the generated command links for your application and produce plain HTML anchor with a target formatted like the generated one.

Comment: The commandLinks should modified object state. If the application found a substring in a string like [moo] than i want, that [moo] replaced with a commandLink like HtmlCommandLink a = new HtmlCommandLink(); /* setValue(), setActionExpression("#{PageController.switchPage(moo)) */ myString.replace("[moo]", a.toString()); -- but that doesn't work, because of HtmlCommandLink doesn't have a overloaded toString() method.

Comment: In your examples, you aren't changing state. You are changing pages, which is what a normal hyperlink does. Can you come up with a better example?

Comment: You are right. I don't say, that getPage set the "Page" member of my managedBean PageController to the specified page-Object. My fail - sorry. My PageController is SessionScoped. But, now i have a solution: i modify the View-Tree with a PhaseListener.

Answer (score 0):

My Soluion:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named("TagViewPhase")
public class TagViewPhase implements Serializable {
    Application app;

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        if (app == null) {
            app = event.getFacesContext().getApplication();
        }
        if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            scanForPageContent(event.getFacesContext().getViewRoot());
        }
    }

    private void scanForPageContent(UIComponent component) {
        for (UIComponent i : component.getChildren()) {
            if ("pageContent".equals(i.getId())) {
                HtmlOutputText content = (HtmlOutputText) i;
                HtmlPanelGroup group = generatePageContent(content);

                content.getParent().getChildren().add(group);
                content.getParent().getChildren().remove(i);
            } else {
                scanForPageContent(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private HtmlPanelGroup generatePageContent(final HtmlOutputText pContent) {
        List<UIComponent> childTree = new ArrayList<>();

        String content = pContent.getValue().toString();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

        Integer start, end = 0;
        String linkValue;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            start = matcher.start();

            if (end < start) {
                HtmlOutputText htmlText = (HtmlOutputText) app.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
                htmlText.setValue(content.substring(end, start));
                childTree.add(htmlText);
            }

            end = matcher.end();
            linkValue = content.substring(start + 1, end - 1);

            HtmlCommandLink link = (HtmlCommandLink) app.createComponent(HtmlCommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);
            link.setValue(linkValue);

            link.setActionExpression(JSFExpression.createMethodExpression(
                    "#{PageController.switchPageByString('" + linkValue + "')}",
                    String.class,
                    new Class<?>[]{}
            ));

            childTree.add(link);
        }

        if (end < content.length()) {
            HtmlOutputText htmlText = (HtmlOutputText) app.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
            htmlText.setValue(content.substring(end, content.length()));

            childTree.add(htmlText);
        }

        HtmlPanelGroup group = (HtmlPanelGroup) app.createComponent(HtmlPanelGroup.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        group.getChildren().addAll(childTree);

        return group;
    }
}
```

xhtml File:

```
<f:view beforePhase="#{TagViewPhase.beforePhase}">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText id="pageContent" value="#{PageController.currentPageContent.text}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</f:view>
```